# BigQuery insert job instead of streaming

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am currently using BigQuery's stream option to load data into tables. However, tables that have date partition on do not show any partitions... I am aware of this being an effect of the streaming.

The Python code I use:

```
def stream_data(dataset_name, table_name, data):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)

    # Reload the table to get the schema.
    table.reload()
    rows = data
    errors = table.insert_data(rows)
    if not errors:
        print('Loaded 1 row into {}:{}'.format(dataset_name, table_name))
    else:
        print('Errors:')
        print(errors)
```

Will date partitioned tables eventually show and if no, how can I create an insert job to realize this?

Comment: _"tables that have date partition on do not show any partitions"_ - can you elaborate a little further on this? We stream to date partitioned tables without any problems.

Comment: In the Web UI I can only see one table. In another dataset (that I did not create) I can see one table but with the amount of partitions in brackets behind the table name and then I am able to query the table with 'tablenameYYYYMMDD'. I want to achieve this.

Comment: Addition: also to be able to use TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Comment: You seem to be getting confused with the new partitioned tables feature, and the old way of doing it i.e. manually creating a partition table for each day.  @Will has explained it perfectly below. Have a read of this - https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "partitions not being shown" but when you create a partitioned table you will only see one single table.

The only difference here is that you can query in this table for date partitions, like so:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mydataset.partitioned_table
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-12-25')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31');
```

As you can see in this example, partitioned tables have the meta column `_PARTITIONTIME` and that's what you use to select the partitions you are interested in.

For more info, here are the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables) explaining a bit more about querying data in partitioned tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I want to achieve is that I can query tables in this way: SELECT * FROM tableYYYYMMDD to simplify queries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Addition: also to be able to use TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Comment: i don't think it's possible to do that using partitioned tables. To use `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` and the `tableYYYYMMDD` maybe you would have to create distinct tables for each day. You still can use partitioned tables to do the same task though, the only difference is that you would select like: `select * from table where _partitiontime = timestamp(date)`  and `select * from table where _partitiontime between date1 and date2` which is equivalent to the table_date_range operation.